# Georeference one image using GCPs from another image

Tags: python, computer-vision, gis, gdal, geotiff

I have two GeoTIFFs, one of which is misaligned spatially. I used opencv to do some quick feature matching between the two to automatically identify GCPs existing in both images. How would I go about warping the misaligned image such that it aligns with source/reference layer? I have the geotransforms for each image and the GCPs in both image and geospace.

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal

reference_image = Image.open(r'reference_image.tif')
target_image = Image.open(r'target_image.tif')
reference = np.array(image1)
target = np.array(image2)

sift = cv2.SIFT_create()

keypoints1, descriptors1 = sift.detectAndCompute(reference, None)
keypoints2, descriptors2 = sift.detectAndCompute(target, None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher()

matches = bf.match(descriptors1, descriptors2)

matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)

matching_result = cv2.drawMatches(reference, keypoints1, target, keypoints2, matches[:7], None, flags=2)

points1 = [(keypoints1[match.queryIdx].pt[0], (keypoints1[match.queryIdx].pt[1])) for match in matches][0:7]
points2 = [(keypoints2[match.trainIdx].pt[0], (keypoints2[match.trainIdx].pt[1])) for match in matches][0:7]

reference_tif = gdal.Open(r'reference_image.tif')
target_tif = gdal.Open(r'target_image.tif')

reference_gt = reference_tif.GetGeoTransform()
target_gt = target_image.GetGeoTransform()

reference_coords = list()
target_coords = list()

for i in range(len(points1)):
    affine_transform = Affine.from_gdal(*reference_gt)
    x, y = affine_transform * (points1[i][0], points1[i][1])
    transformed_points1.append((x, y))

for i in range(len(points2)):
    affine_transform = Affine.from_gdal(*target_gt)
    x, y = affine_transform * (points2[i][0], points2[i][1])
    transformed_points1.append((x, y))
```

[image]

Comment: I assume you want to manipulate the metadata of the geotiff to "place" this image where it is supposed to be? -- is a planar or perspective transform acceptable? GIS works on UTM, i.e. cylinders, doesn't it? you'd need to figure out the mapping between the coordinate system of the image (pixels) and the map. "geotransforms", how do they work? is that just affine or perspective transforms?

Comment: Yes correct, I'm wanting to manipulate the metadata to place the image where its supposed to be. A planar transform is acceptable. I was working to try and inverse the misaligned image's affine transform but wasn't successful. I've updated the post with the code I have thus far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoTIFFs can be georeferenced in two distinct ways: by having GCPs or by having an affine geotransform and an SRS (projection).

I suppose that you want to set a number of GCPs and then to compute an affine geotransform for a given SRS (projection).

There is a GDAL utility for doing this and it is called `gdalwarp`. You can also use it via the Python/C++ API. It is the same utility that is used to reproject images - because this is what you will be doing. The affine geotransform will be computed via a polynomial approximation.

https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to accomplish this with GDAL before my post but wasn't successful. I flipped my GCP points and was able to get it working with gdal_translate! I was accidentally using the pixel coords from the reference image and the geo coords from the target image instead of using the pixel coords from the target image and the geo coords from the reference image.